# Conditional Colorization in Excel if a defined text is not exist

Tags: excel, excel-2007, cells, colorize

I am trying to make a conditional colorization in Excel 2007.
Let me explain in more detail.
If a user writes some desired words (e.g: Alper) in A1 cell there is not problem, but if user write another word (not Alper) then I want to colorize A1 cell as red (as warning).
And i want to do that for all A columns (A1,A2,......AN).
It can be via Script if it'll be valid for all A... columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the A column by clicking on the header. Then click the `Conditional Formatting` button on the ribbon and go to `New Rule`. Choose the option `Format only cells that contain`. You should be able to figure out the options from that point.

This might not sound much like a programming question, but I've found Excel to be fantastic for doing quick and dirty tasks that you thought might require a program.